# angular - Reactive form - disable drop down

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a drop down in Angular reactive form.
I want to disable it on select. But when i use the [disabled]='' attribute directly get this error.

Typescript

```
// Angular Reactive form validation
this.createform = this.formBuilder.group({ENT_TYP_PSD: ''});
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-md-3" for="ENT_TYP_PSD">Type of Natural or Legal Person </label>
  <p-dropdown class="col-md-4" name="ENT_TYP_PSD" [options]="parentEntities" optionLabel="EntityTypeName"
    placeholder="Please select" (onChange)="entityTypeChanged($event)" formControlName="ENT_TYP_PSD" [disabled]='disableEntityType'>
  </p-dropdown>
</div>
```

**Error Message:-**

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
>   directive. If you set disabled to true   when you set up this control
>   in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set
>   in the DOM for   you. We recommend using this approach to avoid
>   'changed after checked' errors.
>
> ```
>   Example:    form = new FormGroup({  first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
> last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)   });
> ```

And when I use this in typescript, I can't get this field ENT_TYP_PSD value at all in the this.createform.value.

```
this.createform.controls['ENT_TYP_PSD'].disable(true)
```

Comment: try using `this.createform.getRawValue()`

Comment: At the time of building the form-group there is only two form-controls are there. That's why you couldn't get it.. can you please add your code snippet here?

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal. Many thanks, mate. that helped

Answer (score 1):

The error means you shouldn't use the `disabled` attribute. Instead, you should programmatically set the disabled state of the input, so that Angualr can keep track of it.

Try removing the attribute and using getter/setter/variable combo :

```
_disableEntityType: boolean
get disableEntityType() { return !!this._disableEntityType; }
set disableEntityType(value: boolean) {
  this._disableEntityType = value;
  this.createForm.get('ENT_TYP_PSD')[value ? 'disable' : 'enable']();
}
```

For the creation :

```
this.createform = this.formBuilder.group({ENT_TYP_PSD: {
  value: '',
  disabled: this.disableEntityType
}});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, once I disable I am not able to get this dropdown actual value.

Comment: You have to use `form.getRawValue()`

Comment: @Jay No problem, if it feels it helped you, consider leaving an upvote and/or closing your question !